# Regex to extract the filename and drop the file timestamp from complete path in Java

Tags: java, regex

i have complete file path and i just need to extract the filename and just extension. So my output would be fileName.csv.

For ex: complete path is:
/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Dir4/Dir5/Dir6/fileName_20150108_002_20150109013841.csv
My output of Regex should be fileName.csv.

Extension and level of directories are not fixed.

As part of my requirement i need single regex that can extract fileName.csv not fileName_20150108_002_20150109013841.csv.how can i do it in single regular expression ?

Comment: `20150108_002_20150109013841` is also part of the *filename*

Comment: It'd be easier if you started by splitting it first.

Comment: You should also try using `File` api. File seperators will be different for windows and Linux .

Answer (score 0):

Below would work for you might be

```
[^\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+$
```

This regex has been tested on these two examples:

\var\www\www.example.com\index.jsp 
\index.jsp

or rather you should use `File.getName()` for better approach.

```
String filename = new File("Payload/brownie.app/Info.plist").getName();
System.out.println(filename)
```

another way is

```
int index = path.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);
String filename = path.substring(index+1);
```

finally after getting the full filename use below **code snippet**

```
String str = filename;// in your case filename will be fileName_20150108_002_20150109013841.csv
str = str.substring(0,str.indexOf('_'))+str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.'));
System.out.println("filename is ::"+str); // output will be fileName.csv
```

Comment: First of all, this is NOT valid java code. Next, this doesn't use the OP's sample input. Next, this also doesn't give what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks ... I want to use Regex for extracting as per my requirement .... i tried with regex given by you ... but it is not extracting the timestamp.... the output is fileName_20150108_002_20150109013841.csv ....  instead of fileName.csv ?? how can i do it in single regular expression ...

Answer (score 0):

*Without using **regex** this can be solved as* -
`public static String getFileName(String args){
         args = args.substring(args.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
         return args.substring(0,args.indexOf('_')) + args.substring(args.indexOf('.'));
     }`

Comment: Thanks ... I want to use Regex for extracting as per my requirement .... i tried different regex but output is fileName_20150108_002_20150109013841.csv .... instead of fileName.csv ?? how can i do it in single regular expression

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, group one will be fileName_timestamp.extension. I've replaced numerics and underscores with empty string. This may look ugly, but still will server your purpose. If the file name contains numerics, we need go for a different approach.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String toBeSplitted = "/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Dir4/Dir5/Dir6/fileName_20150108_002_20150109013841.csv";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)+/?");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(toBeSplitted);
    if(m.matches()){
     String s =  m.group(1).replaceAll("(/|[0-9]|_)", "");
    System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```